# Sql union query can't be fetched

Tags: php, sql, union

Probably this is because the query is not executed properly. It looks like this:

```
SELECT a_email AS email FROM Table_a 
UNION 
SELECT b_email AS email FROM Table_b
```

Two tables with emails, different column names. I want it to select it distinct because of repeated emails. Can `UNION` be constructed as above? If not, how to get the effect another way?

PROBLEM SOLVED as I queried this DB in another way, what brought richer error message. This was

```
Illegal mix of collations
```

Solution is to match both collation methods for this two columns in each tables.

Comment: Do you get an error when running this?  What is it?

Comment: So, you're saying that UNION is not returning a DISTINCT set?

Comment: I'm saying query does not even get executed.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your query seems ok.

If this is causing you problems, it may be the data types are note equivalent.

Try casting both to the same data type and retrying